# Is it possible get an algebraic expression for $\sin 1°$ that does not contain roots of negative values?

Tags: trigonometry, algebraic-number-theory, real-numbers

> Is it possible get an algebraic expression for $\sin 1°$ that does not contain roots of negative values, so that it can be evaluated entirely using only real numbers?

For example, [this paper](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/awards/college.math.j.47.5.322.pdf) gives some algebraic expressions for it, but they all involve complex numbers.

Comment: It seems to be hard dogding the usage of complex numbers here since, as far as I can tell from the given sources, it appears to be common sense reducing the whole problem back to $\sin(3x)=3\sin(x)-4\sin^3(x)$ which leaves us with a cubic equation in $\sin(x)$ $($assuming $\sin(3)$ as known$)$. Solving this invokes complex numbers in a natural way due the general solving formulae for cubic equations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If this would be possible, you could also get an algebraic expression for $\sin(10^o)$ that doesn't contain complex numbers.  That is one of three real roots
of the cubic $8 z^3 - 6 z + 1$. Now see [casus irreducibilis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis): given a cubic with rational coefficients that is irreducible over the rationals and has three real roots, it is impossible to express the roots using real radicals.

Comment: More generally, trig values (when defined) of rational degree angles can be expressed in terms of real radicals if and only if the values are constructible real numbers, a result that Andrzej W. Mostowski proved in [this 1948 paper](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/cm/cm1/cm132.pdf), although the result was known prior to this, possibly by Mostowski himself, although he doesn't say either way in the paper. (This paper appeared in the first volume of **Colloquium Mathematicum**, and the early volume of this journal often published student-authored and student-level non-research papers.)